# Get jetty realm credentials in application

Tags: java, jetty, eclipse-rap

It might be a stupid question but we are using jetty basic authentication on our server. Now we want to use the usercredentials in our application. Is it possible to get the current login in the RAP webapplication?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a RAP expert, but it looks like you want to do this:

```
 HttpServletRequest request = RWT.getRequest();
 Principal user = request.getUserPrincipal();
```